# O(log n) vs O(1)

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree, hashtable

For practical purposes, is hashing significantly better than using a BST? I don't like the fact that hash tables have a lot of things going on under the hood. In practice is log(n) so significantly worse than O(1) that I should avoid using a BST in place of a hash table where possible?

Comment: It all boils down to the constants.  Try benchmarking some cases at different sizes.  "I don't like" != "I have data showing..."

Comment: You choose the data structure in base of the purpose of your objective and use case. O(logN) is worse than O(1). O(1) is the best we can ever expect to obtain. If you want to check if an element exists or find a value given a key HashMap is what you are looking for. If you want to search or find the min/max value or having "always" the O(logN) complexity then Tree and all other variants is what you are looking for.

Comment: You can't choose a data structure in favour of another one only because the you don't like it. As i said, every data structure is suited for some operation that (in some cases) has pros and cons.

Comment: While I certainly agree with all of the comments and answers nobody has yet said the most important one: what makes you in a position to care about the performance implications? What data are you working with and what are you trying to do to it? The type and frequency of operations (read, write, delete, search, random access, sequential access, etc) is going to answer the "which data structure" question, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the one hand, a hash table is (asymptotically) O(1) (IFF you have a O(1) hash algorithm for your data), but potentially O(n) for the occasional write. That is, if you have a suitable hash algorithm. And no adversarial data. Worst-case, someone will feed you data that all hash to the same slot, so both your reads and writes become O(n) (again, with a O(1) hash algorithm).

On the other hand, a BST should be log(n) for reads, and log(n) (although slightly variable) for writes.

In the general case, I'd pick whichever is more convenient to use. In specific cases, I would benchmark, using realistic data.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematically, suppose you have an input of size `2^20`.

To find an element inside the input, a hash would simply perform its O(1) function, no matter what size the input is.

A balanced tree would do log(`2^20`) = 20 operations, which is something around 20.

Now imagine an input of size `2^n`. Which one would you prefer?

---

Obviously this is a simplistic vision of the scenario. Hashes performance can decrease if there are things like repetition of inputs, limited space, bad hashing function, bad hashing approach (there are many approaches and types of hashing, like closed hashing, opened hashing, double hashing, cuckoo hashing, etc.). The mathematical difference is obvious, but as one cannot always guarantee the integrity of all those things just mentioned and inputs of real life don't tend to be so high like `2^50`, sometimes a tree can be better. Obviously a **balanced tree**, not a simple BST, which can take up to O(n) time for all operations.

Comment: Now suppose that the constant for your hash is 1000, while the constant coefficient for the O(log n) operation is 1.  I will never, ever deal with 2^1000 observations (which is more than the estimated number of subatomic particles in the universe).  In that case the O(log) choice is mathematically better than the constant choice throughout the range of applicability.

Comment: This is a wierd supposition to do hehe. Hashes are simple mathematical functions, which perform a few binary functions in the input. Given mathematical constraints, it would be completely useless to have hashes that take contantly 1000 operations, since the input size needed for a tree to do all these operations is 2^1000. Nobody would ever use it knowing that.

Comment: It's a mathematically simplified example of a real-world phenomenon.  Insertion sort is O(n^2), but the constants are such that it beats all of the O(n log n) sorts for n below ~10.  Consequently the best performing sort algorithms are hybrids which switch over at the end stages once the sub-problems get small enough.

Comment: The point is, as I tried to point out in the comment above, in practice it depends on the constants and the domain of applicability.

Comment: Yes. I guess the OP isn't worried about which structure he will use when the input is that small, that's why I brought `2^n`. When the input is that small, even a linear search can perform better than every other option.